# What is the most efficient factoring algorithm for quadratic sieve extraction phase?

Tags: java, algorithm, factorization

In the quadratic sieve algorithm, after finding bSmooth values using logarithmic approximation you need to factor the number, let's call it `B`, to construct the bSmooth vector.

A common solution is to use a trial division using the primes in the factor base. Unlike random numbers, in this case, the trial division is super efficient since most of the factors will be in the prime base. I am saying "most" because a common optimization will allow a small threshold to include 1-3 prims with a product of up to 2^30 or so, it's called a partial relation.

In my [current implementation](https://github.com/gazman-sdk/quadratic-sieve-Java), this vector extraction phase takes most of the time. Another solution that I have been trying to do is receiving, walking again over the prime base, and record the vectors in the indexes knowen to be b-smooth., but that turned to be even slower.

Below is my current code, I added 4 optimizations for the trial division, please tell me if there are better solutions for it.

1. For the prime 2, I check the last set bit of `B` and shift right to extract it.
2. I am using BigInteger `divideAndRemainder` it's optimizing both the memory and the performance by combining the division and the mod actions into 1
3. if `B` is smaller then the max prime in the factor base, then it must be in the factor base, so I use a hash map to locate it's index
4. if no prime up to `B.bitLenght() / 2` is dividing `B` then it must be a partial relation, I will include it only if it's a prime.

```
    private VectorData extractVector(BigInteger value) {
        BitSet vector = new BitSet(PrimeBase.instance.primeBase.size());
        if(value.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0){
            vector.set(0);
            value = value.abs();
        }
        value = extractPower2(value, vector);
        for (int i = 2; i < PrimeBase.instance.primeBase.size(); i++) {
            BigInteger p = PrimeBase.instance.primeBaseBigInteger.get(i);
            int count = 1;
    
            BigInteger[] results = value.divideAndRemainder(p);
            if (results[1].equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
                value = results[0];
                while (true) {
                    results = value.divideAndRemainder(p);
                    if(!results[1].equals(BigInteger.ZERO)){
                        break;
                    }
                    value = results[0];
                    count++;
                }
                if(count % 2 == 1) {
                    vector.set(i);
                }
    
                if (value.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
                    bSmoothVectorData.vector = vector;
                    return bSmoothVectorData;
                } else if (value.compareTo(PrimeBase.instance.maxPrimeBigInteger) <= 0) {
                    int index = PrimeBase.instance.primeBaseMap.get(value);
                    vector.set(index);
                    bSmoothVectorData.vector = vector;
                    return bSmoothVectorData;
                } else if (value.bitLength() / 2 < p.bitLength()) {
                    if (isPrime(value.longValue())) {
                        return new VectorData(vector, value);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

`bSmoothVectorData` is used to differentiate between full and partial relations. The last else-if case that calls for `isPrime` is rare and takes less than 0.001% overall performance of this method, the bottleneck is in the call to `divideAndRemainder` that takes about 72% of the performance.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests using another factoring algorithm that works well on smooth numbers once the smallest primes have been eliminated with trial division: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve#Checking_smoothness_by_sieving

Comment: @DavidEisenstat that will be my last else-if case, it's pretty rare. I think that wiki provides only a high-level overview, they don't talk about optimizations much.

Comment: The idea would be to cut over from trial division before you hit the smoothness bound to something like Pollard's rho.

Comment: I'm not sure what is available in `java` however, I do know that in general exact division can be expensive. For example, in the `C` library `gmp`, there is a function called `mpz_divisible_ui_p` built precisely for your task. From the `gmp` manual: "They use an algorithm which is faster than mpz_tdiv_ui, but which gives no useful information about the actual remainder, only whether it’s zero (or a particular value)."

Comment: Also suggested right below that statement is this: "However when testing divisibility by several small integers, it’s best to take a re- mainder modulo their product, to save multi-precision operations. For instance to test whether a number is divisible by any of 23, 29 or 31 take a remainder modulo 23 × 29 × 31 = 20677 and then test that."... This looks really promising as generally, in your prime base, you have many small primes that you need to test.

Comment: I'm going to have to partially agree with @DavidEisenstat here. I've hacked away at my suggestion above of getting the remainder modulo the product of several small integers and it still doesn't beat my naive trial division (this of course uses the optimized `mpz_divisible_ui_p` which I've already mentioned). I think an interesting idea is to try [ECM-factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) instead of trial division. It can find small divisors quickly. The tricky part is implementing this to ensure that your entire prime factor base is used.

Comment: ... and you are not wasting time on _completely_ factoring it.

Comment: @JosephWood I just submitted an answer, I was able to achieve 80% boost by receiving. I think it will be a good idea to use ECM for partial relations extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve a nearly 80% boost in performance by switching the trial division with receiving. Now, I already mentioned in the question that I tried this before with no success. Well, this time it worked.

I replaced the `BigInteger.mod(x).equals(ZERO)` test with integer operations `(bSmoothData.localX - delta) % prime == startingPosition`, it's probably very specific to my implemintation, but the idea is to check if the prime is supposed to divide the bSmooth index in the sieving array.

Next, I construct a product of all those primes and divide the actual bSmooth value by it, I left then with a reminder that can feet into Java long. And I continue extracting it using trial division. If you are interested in my implementation I made a video about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXg_WrCUX-Q&list=PL0OUqr2O9PxLd35SgBiWIxuLgm7mYksfp&index=16)

Comment: I watched part of the video. The idea you have is really great. If I implement it successfully, I will credit you in my `R` package: [RcppBigIntAlgos](https://github.com/jwood000/RcppBigIntAlgos).

Comment: @JosephWood I am glad you liked it. Good luck with your project!

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, I abandoned this idea for some time, however I revisited it recently and was successful. It will be included in the next release. As promised, I have credited you: [Acknowledgments & Resources](https://github.com/jwood000/RcppBigIntAlgos#acknowledgments-and-resources)

Comment: @JosephWood This is great. Tnx